# How to achieve this using Value animaiton android. or any other way to achieve it

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

[image]

I've created a tab view using a Horizontal Layout, but I'm struggling to implement the desired animation. I've tried using a Value Animator, but haven't been successful. Do you have any suggestions or solutions for this?

I have create the view but not able to replicate the animation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.